# SOAP over JMS using ColdFusion?

Tags: soap, coldfusion, jms, axis

ColdFusion relies on Axis to produce and consume webservice, and it has adaptor to talk to JMS/ActiveMQ.  It also seems to be possible to use Axis to do SOAP over JMS - http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2006/jw-0220-axis.html?page=1

Does CF support invoking webservices over JMS?  If not, is it possible to implement it ourselves, and is it easy?  Does having it implemented mean... async web service call in CF finally?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an asynchronous web service call, just use a thread. The overhead in going from CF->SOAP->JMS->SOAP->service->SOAP->JMS->SOAP->CF would be crazy (when you can just do CF->SOAP->service->SOAP->CF in a thread).

Comment: I read somewhere that JMS > HTTP in terms of robustness, that's why I asked this question.  I guess it really doesn't make too much sense to have so much overhead as you've indicated.  Thanks!